# What is the "Rails Way" to eager loading mutliple associations with multiple aggregations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a simple rails application for a competition with these models: **User**, **Team**, and **Trip**. The associations are: `team has_many users`, and `user has_many trips`. Trips has a `distance_miles` field.

I'm am working on a simple view to display a table of teams with their stats that have multiple aggregations.

My initial approach was the following but results in N+1 queries.

```
@teams.each do |team|
    @team.user.joins(:trips).count()
    @team.user.joins(:trips).sum(:distance_miles)
end
```

The following works, but seems ugly as I want to add pagination, sorting and filtering eventually.

```
@teams = Team.left_joins(users: :trips)
             .select('teams.id, teams.name, SUM(trips.distance_miles) as num_miles, COUNT(trips.id) as num_trips')
             .group(:id)
```

I've been reading preload and includes but cant seem to get it to also get multiple aggregations.  The following gets me part way there, but it is now missing fields from Team and still need the other aggregation:

```
@teams = Team.includes(users: :trips).group(:id).sum('trips.distance_miles')
```

Is there a "rails way" that I'm missing?

Comment: I find using a useful in this cases and building a model on top of that.

Comment: There really isn't much more of a "Rails way" to do that. Rail's ActiveRecord only provides a small subset of all the things a RDBMS can do, this being one of them. If you're looking for a Ruby api to reduce usage of raw strings, you can try using Arel and/or Sequel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord::Calculations which provides `.sum`, `.count` is only really useful in very simple cases as it always creates a separate database query.

You're on the right track with `.select` but it could be cleaned up by extracting the code into the model:

```
class Team
  def self.with_trips
    trips = Trip.arel_table
    self.left_joins(users: :trips)
        .select(
          self.arel.projections, # adds the existing select clause
          trips[:distance_miles].sum.as(:num_miles),
          trips[:id].count.as(:distance_miles)
       )
       .group(:id)
  end
end
```

Using `.eager_load` instead of `.left_joins` will result in a PG::GroupingError on Postgres as the results would be ambiguous. Instead you need use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html).